# Sqlite3: Select data from timestamp to x minutes

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, time

I have a set of data within a database that has a range of entries from a `DATETIME` timestamp.

I am attempting to write a function that selects everything from a start time, to an end time which is defined by `'x minutes'.

So for example, from my test database data set, I want to select everything from `2020-05-04 04:49:05` to `+2 minutes`.

I have read this [sqlite3 date time reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), but can't seem to get it working.

My table schema:

```sqlite3
CREATE TABLE tableTest (TIMESTAMP1 DATETIME DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')),data1 uint8_t,data2 uint8_t,data3 uint8_t,data4 uint8_t,data5 uint8_t,data6 uint8_t,data7 uint8_t,data8 uint8_t);
```

and I have been attempting queries that follow this format, but don't work:

```sqlite3
select * from tableTest where timestamp1 >= strftime('2020-05-04 04:49:02', '+2 minutes');
```

I'm not sure how to correctly format the sql so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `strftime()` is used to format dates.
You should use `datetime()` like this:

```
select * from tableTest 
where timestamp1 between 
  datetime('2020-05-04 04:49:02')
  and  
  datetime('2020-05-04 04:49:02', '+2 minutes');
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Forpas. I tried that however it seems to select everything from the table rather than what is within the 2 minute period (i.e. `'2020-05-04 04:49:02' - '2020-05-04 04:51:02'`)

Comment: In this case `datetime('2020-05-04 04:49:02')` is the same as just `'2020-05-04 04:49:02'`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!